# How to find similar words in Full text search on postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, full-text-search, similarity

I'm trying to use Full text search on postgresql:

```
select *
from entertainement
where to_tsvector('simple', name) @@ to_tsquery('simple', 'word_to_search:*')
```

This query works well and give me what I want to display.However I found on some websites when I enter a word that is not found it shows me `No result found for 'word_to_search'` and give me some other propositions to some words similar to it.
For example if I put the word `activityng` I got

```
No result found for activityng
```

But it gives me some propositions containing word `activity`. However when I put the word `activityns` I got :

```
No result found for activityns
```

But I got some propositions containing the word `activities`. I didn't understand the logic of it because I thnik activityns is similiar to `activity` than to `activities`.
I tried to know the similiarity of this word using `similarity` of `pg_trgm` and I got:

```
select similarity('activity','activityns');
similarity: 0,6666667

select similarity('activities','activityns');
similarity: 0,4666667
```

Is there any other solutions to detect similarity between the words and gives more precise results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FTS first reduce the token to lexeme and then compare, trigram compares three letters - you can't compare comparison results with so different algorithms, hereis example for FTS (showing why one is closerto another in your sample):

```
t=# with w(v) as (values('activityns'),('activity'),('activities'),('activit'))
select to_tsvector(v),v, to_tsvector(v) @@ to_tsquery('activ:*'),to_tsvector(v) @@ to_tsquery('activity'),to_tsvector(v) @@ to_tsquery('activit:*') from w;
  to_tsvector  |     v      | ?column? | ?column? | ?column?
---------------+------------+----------+----------+----------
 'activityn':1 | activityns | t        | f        | t
 'activ':1     | activity   | t        | t        | f
 'activ':1     | activities | t        | t        | f
 'activit':1   | activit    | t        | f        | t
(4 rows)
```

look to which lexeme the word is reduced (first column) and take a look at what results give you wildcard usage depending on lexeme to which the word is reduced (3,4,5) columns

Comment: I understand what do you mean. But I found in some websites they give you some suggestions when you enter 'activityng' it propose words contains the word 'activity' and not 'activities' and when you enter 'activityns' it gives you suggestions with word 'activities' and not 'activity' . Using **to_tsvector** and **to_tsquery** doesn't resolve the problem of the similarity.I tried the pg_trgm to get the similarity of the word entered and the proposition of the website and I find what it gives logic. Thus, I'm trying to know if there is a solution to find similiarity of words.

Comment: what makes you think those sites use postgres?.. (and yes - for similarity nowadays best out of the box postgres solution I would call pg_trgm)

Comment: The suggestion of the words seems like the function of postgresql Full text search.

Comment: you can test the [trivago website] (https://ar.trivago.com/en?sLanguageLocale=UK) if you want to understand about what I'm talking.

Comment: any solutions in 2023?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
        courses.id,
        courses.title,
        courses.description,
        rank_title,
        rank_description,
        similarity
    FROM courses, 
        to_tsvector(courses.title || courses.description) document,
        to_tsquery('sales') query,
        NULLIF(ts_rank(to_tsvector(courses.title), query), 0) rank_title,
        NULLIF(ts_rank(to_tsvector(courses.description), query), 0) rank_description,
        SIMILARITY('sales', courses.title || courses.description) similarity
    WHERE query @@ document OR similarity > 0
    ORDER BY rank_title, rank_description, similarity DESC NULLS LAST
```

https://leandronsp.com/a-powerful-full-text-search-in-postgresql-in-less-than-20-lines